# What is the difference between using upstream and location for php-fpm?

Tags: linux, nginx, configuration, http, php-fpm

I've been searching around but couldn't find a straight answer, if someone could please clarify this, would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files      $uri = 404;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    include        fastcgi.conf;
}
```

OR/AND?

```
upstream php {
    server         unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`location` is used to match expressions and create rules for them.

`upstream` defines servers that can be referenced to.

In your example this means if you want to get an equivalent for

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files      $uri = 404;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    include        fastcgi.conf;
}
```

, you would need

```
upstream php {
    server         unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files      $uri = 404;
    fastcgi_pass   php;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    include        fastcgi.conf;
}
```

The benefit of the upstream block is that you can configure more than one server/port/service as upstream and distribute the traffic on them, for example like this:

```
upstream php {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080       max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    server 192.68.1.2     weight=5;
    server         unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
}
```

You can find more information about this in the nginx documentation:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html

Comment: Do you nee ip_hash for PHP? What about keepalive?

Comment: It should be `fastcgi_pass  php;` instead

Answer (score 9):

I have found that, as of `nginx` 1.6.2 at least, the working syntax for me for the location block is:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files      $uri = 404;
    fastcgi_pass   php;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    include        fastcgi.conf;
}
```

that is: one should not specify the `http://` protocol before referencing the php backend.
The `http://php` syntax is to be used with the `proxy_pass` instruction, not `fastcgi_pass`.